# Div placement even in a single parent and move the other div to the middle

Tags: css, dom

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <div class="title"></div>
   <div class="related"></div>
</div>
<div class="description"></div>
```

As you can see, there are 2 parent divs, `sidebar` and `description`, and 2 child divs within `sidebar`. I have given css rules for them and looks like this picture below :

[image: Aldi Unanto]

**Question** : how can I make the view like this with those markup without change the markup ? :

[image: Aldi Unanto]

*Note : the second will be view if the window's width <= 320px. I have used @media query but the problem is, `title` and `related` are within the one parent (`sidebar`), so it was difficult for me to make them separated and move `description` in the middle of them.

Thanks

Comment: With the help of CSS Media Queries. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Like @VaibhavJain said, you can use the media queries to decide which screen to display, but I don't think you can do this without changing the markup considering description is always under title & related holder.

Comment: I have used @media query but the problem is, `title` and `related` are within the one parent (`sidebar`), so it was difficult for me to make them separated and move `description` between them

Comment: Why don't you want to change the markup? If your markup doesn't represent the structural order / importance of your content then perhaps it *should* change. With regards to the question, the only thing I could suggest is to use absolute positioning and some javascript to calculate heights & positions, it would be an 'unnatural' solution though.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a smart way, but the code below could be a solution for your problem:

HTML:

```
 <div class="sidebar">
     <div class="title"></div>
     <div class="description2"> description ...</div>
     <div class="related"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="description"> description ... </div>
```

CSS:

```
.description2{
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
    .description{
       display:none;
    }
    .description2{
       display:block;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done keeping the two divs within the sidebar (without using javascript). However you can do it like this which makes more sense to me, as it places the description immediately after the title.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Media query</title>
<style>
.title,
.description,
.related {
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 5px;
}
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 620px) {
    .holder {
        width: 620px;
    }
    .title {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .description {
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    .related {
        float: right;
        width:200px;
        height: 390px;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="holder">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="related"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```